# If $p{\le}r$, then r-norm of x is smaller then p-norm of x, where x belongs to lp..

Tags: functional-analysis

It is evident that $l^p$ is a subset of $l^r$.

$l^p$ is space of all sequences, such that $p$-sums are convergent. It is a special case of $L^p$ with $X$ as $\mathbb{N}$ and numbering measure.

How to prove this ?

Comment: What exactly is the statement that you want to prove?

Comment: That lr norm is smaller than lp norm

Comment: @darboux: that is not true. For example $\ell^2(\mathbb N)\not\subset\ell^1(\mathbb N)$.